# Triggers and row versioning information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Under what circumstances will table triggers cause 14 bytes to be added to the end of the row for row versioning?

The "Space Used in Data Rows" section [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492.aspx) clearly states "Each database row may use up to 14 bytes at the end of the row for row versioning information ... These 14 bytes are added the first time the row is modified, or when a new row is inserted, under any of these conditions ... **The table has a trigger**."

This didn't happen in my test (script below). When looking at the data page I don't see any of the versioning info that appears under snapshot isolation. Am I safe in assuming that the rows on data pages will never get bloated by this 14 bytes just because a trigger is on the table? If not when will this occur?

```
CREATE DATABASE D2

GO

ALTER DATABASE D2 SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF

USE D2;

GO

CREATE TABLE T1
(
F1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
F2 INT,
V1 VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO T1
SELECT TOP 80 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS F2,
              REPLICATE(CHAR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0) -1) % 26) + ASCII('A')),100) AS V1
FROM sys.all_columns           

GO      

CREATE TRIGGER TR
   ON  T1
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM inserted

END
GO

UPDATE T1 SET F2=F2+1

GO

DECLARE @DBCCPAGE nvarchar(100)

SELECT TOP 1  @DBCCPAGE = 'DBCC PAGE(''D2'',' + CAST(file_id AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(page_id AS VARCHAR) + ',3)'
FROM T1
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_PhysLocCracker(%%physloc%%) 

DBCC TRACEON(3604)
EXEC (@DBCCPAGE)


GO
```

Comment: The 14 bytes aren't being appended to the row because `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` is set to `OFF` Don't you need to switch this on for the row versioning data to be appended?

Comment: @Barry - It seems so. I was just trying to work out what the link in my question was talking about. Not sure why/when having triggers would make a difference. This was also mentioned without additional explanation in a SQL Server book that I read my best guess is that it is just talking about the `inserted` / `deleted` pseudo tables but not sure why that would merit an entry in the `Space Used in Data Rows` section.

Comment: Probably due to the changes made in SQL2K5 on how the deleted tables were populated by triggers.  Triggers used to scan the transaction log, this was changed to use row level versioning to increase performance. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917674.aspx) in particular the paragraphs following the heading `Additional SQL Server 2005 Features utilizing Row Level Versioning`

Comment: @Barry - That article doesn't answer the question as to why I don't see any of the versioning info in my test though. Turns out it depends on table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all explained [in this blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/31/deletes-that-split-pages-and-forwarded-ghosts.aspx).

The reason why I did not see any versioning pointers in my original test is because of the table definition.

> There is a performance optimization that can avoid adding row
>   versioning information, but only if the table cannot generate
>   `ROW_OVERFLOW` or `LOB` allocation units.  This means that the definition
>   of the table must not allow for LOBs or for the possibility of
>   variable length columns moving off row.  The actual size of the data
>   stored is immaterial – it is the potential size that matters.

If I change the table definition to

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
F1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
F2 INT,
V1 VARCHAR(1000),
V2 VARCHAR(8000) NULL
)
```

So that potentially it might not all fit in row then I do see version pointers in the `DBCC` results. e.g. as below.

```
Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD         Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP VARIABLE_COLUMNS VERSIONING_INFO
Record Size = 133                    
Memory Dump @0x63A4CC92

00000000:   70000c00 03000000 04000000 04004801 †p.............H.         
00000010:   00770044 44444444 44444444 44444444 †.w.DDDDDDDDDDDDD         
00000020:   44444444 44444444 44444444 44444444 †DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD         
00000030:   44444444 44444444 44444444 44444444 †DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD         
00000040:   44444444 44444444 44444444 44444444 †DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD         
00000050:   44444444 44444444 44444444 44444444 †DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD         
00000060:   44444444 44444444 44444444 44444444 †DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD         
00000070:   44444444 444444c8 7b000001 000500b8 †DDDDDDDÈ{......¸         
00000080:   00000000 00††††††††††††††††††††††††††.....                    

Version Information = 
    Transaction Timestamp: 184
    Version Pointer: (file 1 page 31688 currentSlotId 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Paul Randal has a handy article called: ["Inside the Storage Engine: When do versioning tags get added?"](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-When-do-versioning-tags-get-added.aspx). The clue is in the title :-)

Comment: So your conclusion is that there are no circumstances in which the addition of a trigger could increase the row length on the data page by 14 bytes [despite what it says here?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492.aspx). It seems to me that they must only be talking about rows kept in `tempdb` for the `deleted` pseudo table then?

Comment: It isn't something I've looked at, or even thought about. However, I've read again and 14 bytes is a lot for me in my large tables. The fact of "has a trigger" is overkill, surely...

Comment: I couldn't get it to happen in any of my tests or even think of any circumstances in which it would it would be useful under pessimistic concurency. I suspect that it does never happen but will leave the question open in case someone comes in with something that unambiguously states either way...

Comment: [SQL Kiwi shows what they are talking about here I think](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20766/3690)