# Whats the scope of the deleted table that stores the deleted data?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, triggers

I am using  a trigger to keep a log of the deleted data. So whenever the data is deleted it will be inserted to another table.

After deleting the data, then only the trigger gets executed right ? So, How will the deleted data be retrieved to insert into other table. I mean is the data is present somewhere even after it is deleted ? I am assuming that it will be stored in a table called 'Deleted' by analyzing the code.

I need to know where this deleted table is stored? Whats is the scope of it and how long will it hold the data?

Comment: *What* database? Triggers are an area where the different database systems are quite different.

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106372/triggers-and-row-versioning-information) helpful if you're talking about SQL Server.

Comment: On top, RTFM helps. Like reading on triggers when you write them. WOuld - at least for sql server - point to the "deleted" table that contains all deleted rows. During trigger operation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: @Damien yes its SQL server.

Comment: @Ebenezar_Gislen_Softwares And which version? If it is not a secret...

Comment: @ppeterka Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio(2008) 10.0.1600.22

Comment: @Ebenezar_Gislen_Softwares: `SELECT @@VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

You can find this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) usefull to check the **inserted** and **deleted** table.